# Trigger to update existing data or insert if data does not exist (multi-row suppport)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have two tables, both tables contain similar columns of "username", "Date" and "Time". One table (table 2) is essentially a summation of the 'time' column per date where table1 can have multiple "time's" per date.

I have no control over any statements used to insert data into table1 so I thought the best way to do this would be to use a trigger on table1 which **inserts into** or **updates** table2 depending on whether a row is already there for the date(s) inserted. 
To do this, something similar to the following would be fine:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE date = @date/*date from inserted*/)
    --insert into table 2 here
ELSE
    --update table 2 here
```

However, the problem is that I also need multi-row support on the trigger which would result in the previous `IF` failing. One idea would be to loop each row of the insert but from what I've read this will have a big impact on performance which I want to avoid (this is a last resort if there is no better way).

So, is there a way to do what I need *without* using a some kind of loop?

*An example insert which I would be using:*

```
INSERT INTO table2 (username, date, time)
SELECT i.username, i.date, SUM(w.time) FROM inserted AS i
JOIN (SELECT username, date, time FROM table1/*table with trigger*/) AS w 
ON w.date = i.date AND w.username = i.username 
GROUP BY i.username, i.date
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Note: I'm new to SQL so sorry if I'm missing anything/making obvious mistakes!

**EDIT (Solution):**

The working solution (thanks to the answer by @Ronak Vyas) is as follows:

```
MERGE table2 AS m
USING (SELECT i.username, i.date, SUM(w.time) FROM inserted AS i
JOIN (SELECT username, date, time FROM table1/*table with trigger*/) AS w 
ON w.date = i.date AND w.username = i.username 
GROUP BY i.username, i.date) AS s
ON m.date = s.date AND m.username = s.username
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET m.duration = s.duration
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (username, date, time)
VALUES (s.username, s.date, s.time)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to Use Merge Statement.

Visit http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/

Hope, this will help.